# How do I create a column in postgresql to count different values in the same cells of a column that are in varchar format?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

How do I count different values in a cell of a column and put that count in a new column?

for example :

```
 car/bike/truck/pickup/trailer/jeep
```

I want to be able to create a column like 'count of vehicle' with a corresponding value of 6. This is Postgres by the way

Comment: To avoid data inconsistency: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

Comment: However, storing data a slash separated items will only cause you lots of trouble. Redesign!

Comment: That's a horrible way to store things. Do you have a chance to fix the broken design before you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can count different values by `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT vehicle) FROM table;` and set some value to column by `UPDATE table SET different = val`.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the names between slashes as a set using a regular expression. Then, you can count the size of the set.

For example:

```
select count(*) from (
  select regexp_matches('car/bike/truck/pickup/trailer/jeep',
                        '([^/]+)', 'g')
) x
```

Result:

```
count
-----
6
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=069683a6ca496976e49933a12aa6f3d5).

Answer (score 0):

You can turn that value into an array, then count the number of array elements:

```
select cardinality(string_to_array(the_column, '/')) as vehicle_count
from the_table
```

Comment: Hi, just to extend the question, what if in the column, I want to count the number/occurence of only small vehicles such as 'car' and 'bike' in each row of the column? How do I do that?